# My function somehow undo an object property change

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

To calculate the winner of Tic Tac Toe game (I followed the react's [tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html)), I created/modified the `calculateWinner` function. This function accepts an array of objects, whereas each of these objects has 2 properties:

- `value` (which can be set to 'X' or 'O', null by default); and
- `isWinner` (boolean, `false` by default).

What this function does is to check if a certain combination of 3 squares (distinguished by their index in the array) has the same `value`, and change these squares' `isWinner` value to `true`.

The problem is, on certain winning combinations, one or more isWinner property is somehow still set to false when you inspect the whole array itself. To make the problem weirder, this only occurs (so far) on [codepen](https://codepen.io/chrisregner-com/pen/zZXgWy), but not here in StackOverflow's snippet. <del>(I'll try locally soon.)</del> Also erroneous on local.

```js
doTheTest();

function calculateWinner(squares) {
  const lines = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6],
  ];

  let winner = null;

  for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    const [a, b, c] = lines[i];

    let squareA = squares[a];
    let squareB = squares[b];
    let squareC = squares[c];

    if (squareA.value && squareA.value === squareB.value && squareA.value === squareC.value) {
      squareA.isWinner = true;
      squareB.isWinner = true;
      squareC.isWinner = true;

      winner = squareA.value;

      console.log('squares to check:', a, b, c);

      // this returns three trues as expected
      console.log('The three winning values just after setting them:', squares[a].isWinner, squares[b].isWinner, squares[c].isWinner);

      // but if you'll check the three winning square objects in the array,
      // one or more isWinner property is still set to false
      // and for some reason, this only happens in certain winning combinations
      // e.g. it works just fine with [2, 4, 6] but produces this issue with [0, 4, 8]
      console.log('But the squares array itself still just after setting them', squares);
    } else {
      squareA.isWinner = false;
      squareB.isWinner = false;
      squareC.isWinner = false;
    }
  }

  return {
    winner: winner,
    squares: squares
  };
}


function doTheTest() {
 const squaresJSONString = '[{"index":0,"value":"X","coordinates":"1, 1","isWinner":false},{"index":1,"value":"O","coordinates":"2, 1","isWinner":false},{"index":2,"value":"X","coordinates":"3, 1","isWinner":false},{"index":3,"value":"O","coordinates":"1, 2","isWinner":false},{"index":4,"value":"X","coordinates":"2, 2","isWinner":false},{"index":5,"value":"O","coordinates":"3, 2","isWinner":false},{"index":6,"value":null,"coordinates":"1, 3","isWinner":false},{"index":7,"value":null,"coordinates":"2, 3","isWinner":false},{"index":8,"value":"X","coordinates":"3, 3","isWinner":false}]';

 /* The JSON string above in more readable format:
[
 {"value":"X","coordinates":"1, 1","isWinner":false},
 {"value":"O","coordinates":"2, 1","isWinner":false},
 {"value":"X","coordinates":"3, 1","isWinner":false},
 {"value":"O","coordinates":"1, 2","isWinner":false},
 {"value":"X","coordinates":"2, 2","isWinner":false},
 {"value":"O","coordinates":"3, 2","isWinner":false},
 {"value":null,"coordinates":"1, 3","isWinner":false},
 {"value":null,"coordinates":"2, 3","isWinner":false},
 {"value":"X","coordinates":"3, 3","isWinner":false}
]
 */

 const squaresParsed = JSON.parse(squaresJSONString);

 calculateWinner(squaresParsed);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-with-addons.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I see the same result on CodePen and here. They both have `isWinner: true` for indexes 0, 4, and 8.

Comment: You have the same squares in multiple elements of `lines`. So if a square is a winner for one set, but a loser for another set, its final `isWinner` value will be from the last set that included it.

Comment: You should break out of the loop as soon as you find a winning line.

Comment: That is so weird. I just checked mine again, still not working. Check this [screenshot](http://imgur.com/a/nOGfT), do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I didn't break out of the loop immediately because I have to undo any other winners that are previously set.

Comment: I just understood what you said on the second comment. I'll reconstruct my code so that it prevents that issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I certainly overlooked that. How can I vote you up or something for this? @Barmar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to break out of the loop when you find a winning line. Otherwise, you'll keep testing other lines, and since they don't match it will set `isWinner = false;` for those squares, which undoes the assignment when the test succeeded. So put a `break` statement at the end of the `if` block that finds a winning line.

Or if you want to be able to find all winning lines, just leave out the `else` block that sets `isWinner = false`. That should be the initial state of all the objects, you don't need to do it every time through the loop. When the loop is done, all the squares that are part of winning lines will have `isWinner: true`.